# JavaFx Browser support Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, javafx, oracle11g, javafx-webengine

I want to create a simple project in JavaFx, which can support Oracle forms 10g. currently code i'm using can render and HTML page but i unable to render any Oracle forms 10g. Is it possible to run oracle form 10g in javaFx browser and how ?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


  public class Main extends Application {
  private Scene scene;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),900,600, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
                                                                               scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");        
    stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
     class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        // load the web page
        webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);

    }
     private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
       double w = getWidth();
       double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
   }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 900;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 600;
   }
}
```